# blutooth not sending images to another device

Tags: android, bluetooth

> 

I am a new for android development.I have created one bluetooth application for sending image to another device from my application.
First i load the image from gallery and using this uri to send that image into remote device.And using the search button to search the possibility devices which is visible one list view.
My problem is when i am click the list view(remotedevice address)the remote device could not be paired and also not sending images.please help me thanks...`

> My xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_search"
    android:text="Search for listener"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/text_message"
    />
     <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnidOpenGallery"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button_listen"
            android:text="OpenGallery" />


    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_discovered"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/btnidOpenGallery"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

> My MainActivity:

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            btnOpenimage=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnidOpenGallery);
            OpenImage();
            foundDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
            configureBluetooth();
            setupListView();
            }



    private void configureBluetooth() {
            bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        }

    private void OpenImage() {
            btnOpenimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                                "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                    }
                });
        }

    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode==2) {
                    selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                }
             }


    private void setupSearchButton() {
            Button searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_search);

            searchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    registerReceiver(discoveryResult, new IntentFilter(
                            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));

                    if (!bluetooth.isDiscovering()) {
                        foundDevices.clear();
                        bluetooth.startDiscovery();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private void setupListView() {
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_discovered);
            aa = new ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, foundDevices);
            list.setAdapter(aa);

            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int index,
                        long arg3) {
                    AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> connectTask = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                            try {
                                BluetoothDevice device = foundDevices
                                        .get(params[0]);
                                socket = device
                                        .createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
                                socket.connect();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.d("BLUETOOTH_CLIENT", e.getMessage());
                            }
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                            //switchUI();
                            try {
                                sendFile(selectedImageUri, socket);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    connectTask.execute(index);
                }
            });
        }



        public void sendFile(Uri uri, BluetoothSocket bs) throws IOException {
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
            OutputStream os = bs.getOutputStream();
        try {
            int bufferSize = 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // we need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the byteBuffer
            int len = 0;
            while ((len = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        } finally {
            bis.close();
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            bs.close();
        }
    }
```